Google Cloud SQL MySQL 8.0 only accepting connections after external connection
I upgraded mysql from 5.7 to 8.0.37 on GCP Cloud SQL. Now, when the db is restarted (manually or for maintenance), it does not accept connections from a GCP Cloud Run Java server with this error:
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user

Only when I log in via some external tool (IntelliJ DataGrip JDBC in my case) everything suddenly starts to work as soon as the connection is established.
What could be the problem?
